# Visual Studio 2012 JavaScript Intellisense Reference Group Reverts to Implicit (Windows)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I have set up my IDE to show JS Intellisense based on references set in _references.js (http://blog.craigtp.co.uk/post/Javascript-jQuery-Intellisense-in-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx).  In doing so, you have to set JavaScript IntelliSense Reference Group to "Implicit (Web)", which I've done.  For some time, it works beautifully.

However, after some seemingly random amount of time (could be hours or days, but not usually more than a day or so), my JS IntelliSense stops working.  When I go back to the Reference Group settings, I find that the Reference Group has reverted back to "Implicit (Windows)".

Does anyone else have that problem?  What might be causing that, or is this a bug in VS2012 (this is the released version)?

Thanks!

Comment: In VSTO 2013 Update 2 (Win 8, 32 bit), I could not get this working despite adding the reference manually (as Robert Levy) suggested. Surprisingly, it appears that if I just close and reopen the solution, Visual Studio is happy. I get the two extra menu items upon right-clicking on _reference.js. Weird! Do not quit VSTO, just close the solution and reopen - looks like second attempt onwards, VSTO picks up the settings for intellisense. Posting this comment, just in case someone is going through this issue like us. I believe this is an active bug being tracked (I see it in Open status).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it changes on you but I found that this trick still works when set to Windows if you manually add the reference to ~/scripts/references.js